# Пользователям приходит некорректная ссылка

Tags: php, sms

Имеется система верификации пользователя с отправлением подтверждающей ссылки по номеру телефона. В БД ссылка записывается корректно, также в личном кабинете сервиса массовой рассылки текст (ссылка) отображается у всех пользователей корректно.
Протестировал на сотовых операторах Yota, Megafon, MTS - во всех случаях ссылка приходит корректная.
Но по Вебвизору в системе Яндекс Метрика заметил, что у некоторые пользователи (около 6-7 %) переходят по ссылке формата **http://desavir.ru/site/confirm?key=1c7f943e2a59?1613040553** а не **http://desavir.ru/site/confirm?key=1c7f943e2a59_1613040553**, то есть нижнее подчеркивание заменяется на знак вопроса (у кого то на знак параграфа и т.д). Чем может быть вызвана данная проблема и какая есть альтернатива этому разделителю. После разделителя идет timestamp, не очень хотелось бы его убирать и делать ссылку бессрочной.

Зависит ли это от сотого оператора или модели телефона?

p.s
Служба поддержки массовой рассылки советует использовать символа UTF-8, насколько я знаю, нижнее подчеркивание входит в список этих символов.

Comment: Попробуйте `urlencode` метод

Comment: @mepihindeveloper, "Возвращает строку, в которой все не цифро-буквенные символы, кроме -_. должны быть заменены знаком процента (%)", данный метод никак не видоизменяет передаваемый атрибут ```key```

Comment: Офтопик, но если я поменяю в ссылке таймштамп на `2613040553` то она же станет бессрочной.

Comment: @u_mulder, предполагаю, что 99% пользователей сайта, обслуживанием которого я занимаюсь, не знают об этом.

Comment: без разделения ключа на составные части таймстамп  было бы заметить сложнее, а вырезать последние 10 символов из ключа в коде труда не составит. Либо еще как-то скрыть, написав, его, к примеру, задом наперед. тогда будет не 99% а 99.99%. (оффтопик немного)

Comment: акксесс логи мб включить, и посмотреть по факту, а не по яндекс метрики? может какая-то взаимосвязь будет между запросами?

Comment: так и лепи ссылку без разделителя key=1c7f943e2a591613040553, на сервере её же запросто можно распилить на две части

Comment: Я предлагаю сделать json и упаковать его в base64. Получится стильно, модно, современно

Comment: @ArchDemon не велика ли ссылка будет для СМС ?

Comment: @teran, да, так и сделал, спасибо большое! Зациклился на разделителе и даже не подумал о его удалении из ссылки...

Comment: @DrMcSheen, Да, так и сделал, спасибо большое за наводку!

Comment: @ArchDemon, действительно, ссылка получается слишком большой и не укладывается в допустимый размер одного СМС сообщения.